# Would a bicycle pump work underwater, with its air-input being above water?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Let say I have a bicycle pump 10m underwater, with its air input following an inflexible tube to the surface. Would the bicycle pump be harder to either pull or push?

What would be the pressure inside the tube? If it is higher than the surface pressure, how could the pressure be high in one end of the tube, and low in other?

I'll place a diagram to visualize.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: FYI: If you disassemble a _real_ bicycle pump—not usually difficult—you will find it simpler than you imagine. There is no separate "air input" port. On the draw stroke, the piston seal contracts, allowing air from behind the piston to flow around it and in to the compression chamber, and then on the push stroke, the pressure in the chamber expands the piston seal against the cylinder wall, trapping air in the chamber. @AccidentalTaylorExpansion's answer, below, illustrates the principle, but the implementation is even simpler than what that illustration shows.

Comment: @SolomonSlow if there's no air inlet on the side behind the piston, where is the air coming from to refill the cylinder?

Comment: @Holloway, the space behind the piston in a typical bicycle pump communicates with the atmosphere through the same hole in the end cap that the shaft goes through. The shaft typically fits loosely through that hole. AccidentalTaylorExpansion drew it as a separate hole in the end cap, but that's part of why I said that the reality was somewhat simpler than AccidentalTaylorExpansion's drawing. ATE's drawing also seems to show a one-way valve in the piston, but I'm saying that typically, the piston seal _is_ the one-way valve: it seals when you push the handle down, but not when you pull it up.

Comment: Really simple bike pumps don't even have a valve on the out port... they rely on the tube from the pump to the tyre having a small working volume and the valve in the tyre stopping the pumped air flow back on the back stroke.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Your statement might be true for small portable pumps. But I don't think it is true in general. Especially for larger floor pumps but also some portable ones. See for example the answer here that highlights the location of the air inlet valve for a Bontrager floor pump https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/67300/what-is-the-typical-structure-and-location-of-a-check-valve-in-a-floor-pump

Comment: @user2705196, Other than one comment that merely says a pump must have an inlet valve, I don't see the word "inlet" anywhere in that posting. The kind of pump I am talking about _does_ have an inlet valve, but if you go looking for it you might not immediately recognize that the inlet valve and the piston skirt are the same thing.

Comment: @SolomonSlow My point is that the "kind of pump you are talking about " is not all pumps. Especially floor pumps *do* have a seperate "air input port". For an example check out the above link to see a case where the inlet valve is clearly *not* the piston skirt.

Comment: @user2705196. Yes. You are exactly right. I am not talking about all pumps. OP asked specifically about a "bicycle pump," but showed a pump in their diagram that is not built like a typical bicycle pump. Answers below speak to the pump in the diagram, and that's fine, but I thought that the OP might be interested to know that most _actual_ bicycle pumps do not work the same as the pump in the diagram. (e.g., most would not be capable of pumping air if the back of the piston was open to the surrounding water.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Your point is definitely useful for understanding how certain bike pumps work! My point was to improve its utility by pointing out that many *actual bicycle pumps* do work with a specific air input port that the OP indicated. Namely, most (all?) floor pumps but also some portable ones like this one https://www.topeak.com/us/en/product/245-MOUNTAIN-MORPH. Of course one would need a hose to connect the air input port to the surface as drawn in the diagram which is impractical. But I don't think this was a practical question in the first place...

Comment: @user2705196, If you say that there is some way you could attach a snorkel tube to the air inlet of the MOUNTAIN-MORPH pump, and be able to pump air with it while the pump is submerged like in OP's drawing, then I'll have to take your word for that. The page that you linked doesn't answer the question, and the five minutes that I was willing to spend searching for info on-line didn't turn up anything helpful either.

Answer (score 6):

So let's look at the forces that act on the moving piston.

We have water on one side (which we assume for simplicity that it has constant pressure over the stroke) and air on the other side.

So let's start a pump cycle with the piston in the position where there is no (or minimal) air in the cylinder. We pull out the piston. On one side we have air pressure basically the same as at the surface, on the other side of the piston we have the water pressure which depends on the depth. Because it seems simpler right now I'm using Bar instead of Pascal for pressure.

Per 10m depth we have one Bar of pressure added. 1 Bar is 1kg/cm^2. Which means that if our piston has an area of 10cm^2 at a depth of 10m we will need the equivalent force of lifting a mass of 10kg at the surface (around 100N)

Now let's see what the forces are if we want to push out that air. Again assuming that the pump, opening, piston and everything has the same pressure all around.

We now need to compress the air to the pressure of the opening which is also 1m under water. So it needs a pressure of 1bar. Again with 10cm^2 this will give a force equivalent to lifting 10kg at the surface. But at the same time we have the same force pressing from the water on the other side of the piston, so basically zero force is needed to push the air out (dismissing any friction and stuff).

So, if the pump is at the target pressure level you need force to pull air into the comression chamber but basically no force to get the air out.

Comment: Cheers thats sound all good, appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

> Would the bicycle pump be harder to either pull or push?

Harder. Air output now is presented with additional $\Delta P_{10m} = \rho g h \approx 98~\text{kPa}$ pressure, for getting out of pump, instead of $1~\text{atm}$ while pumping in the air. In addition, while pumping in the water, - your hand will experience $\approx 816 \times$ higher drag force comparing with pumping in the air, due to a lot higher surrounding fluid density.

Answer (score 4):

> How could the pressure be high in one end of the tube, and low in
> other?

There are two valves inside a bicycle pump (see picture below). Before you press down the inlet valve is open: the one that is connected to the air. The pressure inside the pump is equal to atmospheric pressure (I'll neglect the increase in air pressure due to depth for a second since it is only 10m). When you start pumping the inlet valve will close shut and the pressure starts increasing because you are compressing the air. Once the pressure inside the pump is higher than the pressure outside the outlet valve will open and air starts escaping.

I suspect that initially it would be equally hard to press down the handle since the pressure inside is independent of the pressure outside the pump. But while a pump functioning in normal conditions would quickly open the outlet valve, the pressure inside the underwater pump would keep increasing before it could release some air. So overall it would be harder to use the pump. But to be honest I'm not quite sure about this.

[image]

source of image: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221249358_Lines_Blobs_Crosses_and_Arrows_Diagrammatic_Communication_with_Schematic_Figures

Comment: Quite right, a lot depends upon the pressure exerted by the air in the inflated object. 28psi is about 2 atmospheres. 10m of salt water is close enough to 1. Then there is the fact you may need less pressure in the tyre due to less weight or the risk of over-inflation at lower depths.